# how to access ref react native with a functional component

Tags: react-native, expo

i have a functional component and im trying to get the ref from a view inside a flatlist, since im trying to use the takeSnapshotAsync(view, options) function from expo and i need access to that view to pass it to the expo function, any help is aprecciated.

```
<FlatList
          data={images}
          keyExtractor={(images) => images.created_at}
          renderItem={({ item }) => { 

            return (
              <View style={{ borderRadius: 15, overflow: 'hidden', marginLeft: 0 }} ref={ref => {
                const viewRef = ref}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef`, as described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref